# why won't list show in simulator or on device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

I have made a iPhone/iPad app (with watch app) in Xcode 13.3.1 and can't figure out how to get the list to show (I don't see why it isn't showing). the issue is both in simulator and on device. I have marked the list in the code

```
import SwiftUI
struct Period: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    //Day for the period
    let day: Day
    let id = UUID()
}
struct Day: Hashable{
    let weekday: Days
    let schedule: Schedule
}
enum Days: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable{
    var id: String{
        rawValue
    }
    case monday
    case tuesday
    case wednesday
    case thursday
    case friday
}
enum Schedule: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable{
    var id: String{
        rawValue
    }
    case a
    case b
}
```

there is more of the following variable I have just shown an example to make it more readable.

```
private var schedule = [
Period(name: "rateing: 3", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "form", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "Maths", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "Break", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "Science", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "French", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "Lunch", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "English", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "Re", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),
Period(name: "extra library help", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .a)),


Period(name: "rateing: 3", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "form", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "Maths", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "Break", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "Science", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "French", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "Lunch", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "English", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "Re", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
Period(name: "extra library duty", day: .init(weekday: .monday, schedule: .b)),
]
```

if the rest of the list is required then sorry and I will provide.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var current = 5.0
    @State private var minValue = 0.0
    @State private var maxValue = 13.0
    @State private var track = 1.0
    
    let gradient = Gradient(colors: [.green, .yellow, .orange, .red])
    
    @State var re = false
    @State var science = false
    @State var maths = false
    @State var english = false
    @State var history = false
    @State var geography = false
    @State var dt = false
    @State var art = false
    @State var computeing = false
    @State var drama = false
    @State var music = false
    @State var french = false
    @State var german = false
    
    @State var task = 0
    @State var Bre = 0
    @State var Bscience = 0
    @State var Bmaths = 0
    @State var Benglish = 0
    @State var Bhistory = 0
    @State var Bgeography = 0
    @State var Bdt = 0
    @State var Bart = 0
    @State var Bcomputeing = 0
    @State var Bdrama = 0
    @State var Bmusic = 0
    @State var Bfrench = 0
    @State var Bgerman = 0
    
    @State var selectedday: Day? = nil
    @State var selection: Options = .list
    //Contains a filtered list if `selectedday != nil`
    var filteredSchedule: [Period]{
        schedule.filter({ period in
            if let selectedday = selectedday {
                return period.day.weekday == selectedday.weekday && period.day.schedule == selectedday.schedule
            }else{
                return true
            }
        })
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressView(value: current/13)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(height: 20.0)
                
        // homework
            HStack {
                VStack{
                    Toggle("Re", isOn: $re)
                    Toggle("English", isOn: $english)
                    Toggle("Dt", isOn: $dt)
                    Toggle("French", isOn: $french)
                }
                VStack{
                    Toggle("Science", isOn: $science)
                    Toggle("History", isOn: $history)
                    Toggle("Art", isOn: $art)
                    Toggle("German", isOn: $german)
                    Toggle("Drama", isOn: $drama)
                }
                VStack{
                    Toggle("Maths", isOn: $maths)
                    Toggle("Geography", isOn: $geography)
                    Toggle("Computeing", isOn: $computeing)
                    Toggle("Music", isOn: $music)
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal).toggleStyle(.button).foregroundColor(Color.black)
            
                            
            Divider().padding(.vertical)   // homework timetable divide
            
        // timetable
            
            ScrollView{
```

the lists below

```
                HStack { 
                    List {
                        Text("Score:")
                        Text("Registration")
                        Text("P1")
                        Text("Break")
                        Text("P2")
                        Text("P3")
                        Text("Lunch")
                        Text("P4")
                        Text("P5")
                        Text("Club")
                    }
                    List(filteredSchedule) {
                        Text($0.name)
                            .font(.body)
                            .padding(.all)
                    }
                }  
            }
```

the rest of the code

```
            Divider()
                .padding(.vertical)   // timetable - picker divide
            
        // timetable picker
            
            Picker(selection: $selectedday, label: Text("")){
                Text("pick day here").padding(.top).tag(nil as Day?) //Types must match exactly
                ForEach(Days.allCases, id:\.id){ dCase in
                    Group{
                        Text("A - ".capitalized) + Text("\(dCase.rawValue)".capitalized)
                    }
                    .tag(Day(weekday: dCase, schedule: .a) as Day?) //Types must match exactly
                    Group{
                        Text("B - ".capitalized) + Text("\(dCase.rawValue)".capitalized)
                    }
                    .tag(Day(weekday: dCase, schedule: .b) as Day?) //Types must match exactly
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    enum Options{
        case list
        case selection
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need two `List`'s, why not use Section and have  a single `List` with multiple sections. With the given example, it's hard to see what you exactly the end goal looks like.

Comment: @Cole no the 1st list was just something I wanted to try out however the issue remains when there is just 1 list, the end goal is to have a list of a days schedule with the time period (score, registration etc) to the left